# ngOnInit does not work second time in modal form

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I've created a component to be opened as modal form and placing it to my form like below:

```
<app-customer-definition [customerCode]="null" (save)='customerSave($event)' (cancel)='customerCancel()'></app-customer-definition>
```

and opening form with below button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="btnNewCompanyClick()" data-target="#mdlCustomerDefinition">
  <span>
    <i class="la la-plus"></i>
    <span>New Customer</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

I'm passing `customerCode` as an input parameter. If `customerCode` equals null, modal form creates a new customer instance, `customerCode` is defined modal form get customer data for update in `ngOnInit`.

For the first call, modal form is opened and works as expected. But in the other calls `ngOnInit` is not triggered, so my logic does not work. Should I change my logic (how) or how can i run my logic in `ngOnInit` or other event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EnesKöroğlu, I have updated the code, stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cam1b8 use this link to view it, its working fine, according to your requirement

Comment: Thank you for your effort and yes this is the working solution.

Answer (score 1):

using the bootstrap4 modal you just hide & showing the modal first time you   the click button then the modal instance come & when you remove the modal than its just hide but it is present in the DOM, when the modal income in action the component inicialized & the noOnInit work but when you open the modal second time the modal just reopen but it does not make the new instance of the component,

instead of noOnInit you can use ngOnChange method of lifecycle hook method of angular2 or ngDoCheck

Comment: Thanks for your reply but `ngOnChanges` works once on main form opened, `ngDoCheckis` working without stop (nearly infinite). Unfortunately both suggestions, did not work :(

Comment: please use ngif condition & make the variable true & false frequently it will going to remove the element from the dom & again going to add it

Comment: I did not understand where to you use `ngIf`, what will I do with boolean variable and when should I set it.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loaded mark that variable as false. When you load the modal the then mark the value as again false & at very next line mark that variable as true,
example:-

```
var a=false;
  constructor(){
    this.a = false;
   }

<button **(onclick)="methodCall()"** type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button><div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content" **ngif= "a"** >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

```
 methodCall(){
  this.a = false;
  this.a = true;
  }
```

please use this way it resolve my issue also, also have the issue related to that only

Comment: Could not make this demo work on stackblitz completely but if you can look this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8s219e) `DoCheck` is triggered normally while modal is created. But while modal closing `DoCheck` event works 3 times. I need an event which works on modal show one time on every modal creation/show.

Comment: hey, @EnesKöroğlu, I have updated the code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cam1b8 use this link to view it,
its working fine,